# How to use REST API in julia

Tags: api, julia

I am trying to use `API` in Julia. I have a few questions,

1. Which is the best package to use for API with machine learning capabilities?
2. What is the correct syntax for POST based operations, is there any good docs which the community can recommend for better understanding?

I have tried to write a small code to access the free API from `rapidapi` in Julia, however, I fail to manage it to work.

```
using HTTP
url = "https://community-open-weather-map.p.rapidapi.com"
api_key = "123456789"
function get_data()
    resp = HTTP.get(
        url;
        query = [
        "X-Rapidapi-Key" => "$api_key",
        "get" => "weather", "tempmax", "visibility", "wind", "timezone"
        ]

    )
end
get_data()
```

Please suggest solutions to build a more stable API code. Also, please do recommend any detailed tutorial to get a better understanding of this topic.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `HTTP.jl` is the way to go when interfacing with a REST API in Julia. "When to find leaeninig materials" is a too broad question for SO. You could perhaps start with this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S25F2WfNhMU

Comment: Thanks @PrzemyslawSzufel, awesome !!!